# Abelian variety associated to Hilbert modular forms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Is there any construction of Abelian variety associated to Hilbert modular forms with arbitrary nebentypus?
I am aware of the   Sho-Wu Zhang's 2001 Annals paper for $\Gamma_0(N)$ under Jacquet-Langlands condition. 
Is there any generalization of the construction for arbitrary nebentypus under certain Jacquet Langlands condition and restriction on the degree of the field in question.